# How to work with a Class that Implements Runnable in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am not so new to threads, I basically use threads to run long processes, all i do is create an instance of the `Runnable` class and put all the code I want it to run in the `run()` method, but yesterday my lecturer gave me a task to create a simple program that implements the `Runnable` class, with that class am to demonstrate how to use the `Start(), Wait(), Sleep(), Join() and Yield()` method calls, like I said early every time I want to run a thread all I do is create an instance of the  `Runnable` class and add a `handler` or even a `Looper` but implementing the class is something I have never done before so I am a bit lost, I choose to create a simple Contactbook program, the program is to save and delete Contacts from a file, one of these classes should implement the `Runnable` class, so I choose the class that saves and loads contacts from a file because this part might take more time hence it needs to run on a separate thread below are my classes

Person class (a blueprint of which data each contact should have)

public class Person implements Runnable{

```
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String number;
private String callTime;


public Person()
{
    this("", "","","");
}

public Person(String fname, String lname, String number, String callTime)
{
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.number = number;
    this.callTime = callTime;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
    this.lname = lname;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getCallTime() {
    return callTime;
}

public void setCallTime(String callTime) {
    this.callTime = callTime;
}

public void printContacts()
{
    TimeAgo timeSaved = new TimeAgo();
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" 1. First Name: "+this.fname);
    System.out.println("    Last Name: "+this.lname);
    System.out.println("    Cell Number: "+this.number);
    System.out.println("    Saved Date: "+String.valueOf(timeSaved.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(this.callTime))));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

}
```

}

Contactmanager class, the class is responsible for writing, reading and deleting contacts from the file, the `readAllContacts and writeToFile` methods are the ones I want to run on another thread, basically because they might take a bit of time reading and writing. So my question is how can I tell the `ContactManager` to run the two methods on a separate thread without need of creating an instance of the `Runnable` class and surrounding the method bodies in the `run()` method?

Comment: You cannot run a method in another Thread without creating a new Thread. If you implement Runnable you need to override the run() method then you can put this class in a new Thread and start it.

Comment: I suggest you start with something simplier, since you need to demostrate Start(), Wait(), Sleep(), Join() and Yield(), you need two threads, that works togheter, search  for this on google [java thread example]

Comment: Thank @PetterFriberg

Comment: @Tobi thanks as well